# Вывести число похожих слов из файла.Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Есть код, который берёт html сайта и записывает его в текстовый файл.Потом находит похожие слова по заданной сигнатуре и выводит их число. По крайней мере он должен так работать.Но возникла проблема: он не сканирует html код в текстовом документе. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему?

```
import urllib.request
import csv
res = urllib.request.urlopen("http://kcybs.com").read()
file_name = "C:\\Users\\tk240\\Desktop\\Qtest\\test.docx"    # путь к файлу
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
f.write(res)
w="html"
f = open(file_name,encoding='utf8')
f.read()
f.close()
c=file_name.count(w)
while c > 0:
  print(c)
  c -= 1
```

Comment: `f.read()` - тут вы прочитали данные из файла, но никуда не записали. Потом в имени файла зачем-то пробуете считать сколько раз встречается "слово" html.

Comment: после того как прочитал, нужно ещё раз записывать куда-то?

Comment: не после а во время тоесть выглядеть должно приблизительно так `var_txt = f.read()` и вот уже с переменной `var_txt` работаете дальше как с текстом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это должно помочь.

```
import urllib.request 
import csv 
res = urllib.request.urlopen("http://kcybs.com").read() 
file_name = "C:\\Users\\tk240\\Desktop\\Qtest\\test.docx" # путь к файлу 
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res) 
w="html" 
with open(file_name,encoding='utf8') as f:
    text_f=f.read() 
c=text_f.count(w) 
while c > 0: 
    print(c) 
    c -= 1
```